# How can I reproduce Collection example in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, list, linq, collections

I want to read a big number of strings in different files in Excel, and create a group with them.

If I understood correctly, as I don't know how many strings I will have, it is better to use Collections instead of arrays.

I just want to reproduce now [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/collections) to learn how to work with Collections.

```
' Create a list of strings.  
Dim salmons As New List(Of String)  
salmons.Add("chinook")  
salmons.Add("coho")  
salmons.Add("pink")  
salmons.Add("sockeye")  

' Iterate through the list.  
For Each salmon As String In salmons  
    Console.Write(salmon & " ")  
Next  
'Output: chinook coho pink sockeye
```

I have not modified anything, and it is giving me

> Compile error: Expected: end of statement

A note says

> For the examples in this topic, include Imports statements for the
>   System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq namespaces.

I did it and the problem is still there.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is .NET which is completely different from VBA.

In VBA you do this:

```
Dim salmons As Collection  
Set salmons = New Collection

salmons.Add "chinook"
salmons.Add "coho"
salmons.Add "pink" 
salmons.Add "sockeye" 

Dim item as Variant

' Iterate through the list.  
For Each item In salmons  
    Debug.Print item 
Next  

Set salmons = Nothing
```

**Edit**:

---

Since you are new to VBA, for future reference keep in mind, VBA supports the [With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/with-statement) statement. Therefore the above example could have been written like this:

```
With salmons
    .Add "chinook"
    .Add "coho"
    .Add "pink" 
    .Add "sockeye" 
End With
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you know where can I find the equivalent documentation for VBA?